# EF not generating between clause

Tags: c#, entity-framework

The clause `Where(i => i.TimeSt >= date1 && i.TimeSt =< date2)` is not being translate to `where TimeSt between @date1 and @date2` . How can I tell EF to use it?

**Edit1**
this is a simplified version of the query. The original one handles over 17 dates.

**Edit2**
`date1` and `date2` are standards .Net DateTime objects that has significant date part and time part (e.g.: 2017-01-05 21:15:21.123)

Comment: Why you says that? Have you seen generated sql statement? Or your query is not working?

Comment: Why you want that? `BETWEEN` is not better than `> ... <`, actually it's different. Your query excludes these times but BETWEEN includes them.

Comment: what does it generate?

Comment: @TimSchmelter because date1 might be bigger than date2 and regular sql already handles that in the between statement... and my bad on the `>= <=` typo

Comment: @dasblinkenlight because the results are different

Comment: thats not the same thing as you have written in this expression

Comment: @RobertoConteRosito results are not as expected yes...

Comment: @LukeMcGregor how should i write it then?

Comment: @Leonardo try to use use >= and <= instead of < >

Comment: .Where(i => i.TimeSt >= date1 && i.TimeSt <= date2)

Comment: @peval27 same result... i did that already

Comment: @dasblinkenlight sorry, my typo here...

Comment: @kogelnikp that was my typo... sorry

Comment: @Leonardo could you tell us what are date1 and date2? It might be that the date is truncated therefore it's not generating the same results

Comment: @peval27 check edit 2

Comment: Are you sure that SQL handles the situation when `@date2 < @date1` differently from EF? Because according to [the documentation](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187922.aspx) it doesn't.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight: no, it doesn't handle it. I'd really recommend to avoid `BETWEEN` since it causes more issues than it solves. Read: [What do BETWEEN and the devil have in common?](https://sqlblog.org/2011/10/19/what-do-between-and-the-devil-have-in-common)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simple answer is that you cant out of the box do this. There is some magic in EF7 which will allow you to hand taylor this part of the query (but as others have noted this seems like overkill), Check out their tests for an example

```
from o in context.Set<Order>().FromSql(@"SELECT * FROM ""Orders"" WHERE ""OrderDate"" BETWEEN {0} AND {1}", startDate, endDate)
where c.CustomerID == o.CustomerID
....
```

https://github.com/aspnet/EntityFramework/blob/1fa247b038927a7d7438f666dc11253f64e0432d/src/Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.Relational.Specification.Tests/AsyncFromSqlQueryTestBase.cs#L98

Perhaps a better solution would be to write your own between extension method which swaps the order of the args around automagically, or just do it before the query

or if you want it to automatically swap them, put both the orderings in the query `(i => (i.TimeSt >= date1 && i.TimeSt =< date2) || (i.TimeSt >= date2 && i.TimeSt =< date1))`